# Is this verb agreement right?

Tags: verb-agreement

> The design of the green and blue tiles on the wall remind people of the sea, while the curved window frames were inspired by ocean waves.

I can’t understand the form of verb *remind.*

I thought it has to be *reminds* since the subject is *design.*

Comment: You are correct. The sentence is ungrammatical; the use of "remind" might have been influenced by the presence of the plural noun "tiles" earlier in the sentence, even though it is not the subject. Or the speaker/author might have been thinking of the alternative, grammatically correct sentence "The design**s** of the green and blue tiles on the wall remind people of the sea, while the curved window frames were inspired by ocean waves."

Answer (score 1):

'Design' is the subject of the sentence. It has the post-attributive group with 'of'. The verb form must be agreed with the subject. So the only possible form is 'reminds'.

Answer (score -5):

"Design" is a noun while blue and green are "adjectives" leaving the word "tiles" as the subject and since tiles is in plurar the verb shouldn't have an "s" so "remind" is fine.

Comment: How can tiles be a subject? I can’t understand